# How do you size the jQuery Button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI Button control but don't seem to be able to adjust the size (width and height). Here's the [API documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button). I tried setting a STYLE attribute on it, but then the LABEL wasn't centered correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried to give it a width via firebug, It works and centers correctly.

Comment: Width works, but not height. To change height, use padding-top and padding-bottom as suggested below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this in the style attribute:

```
width: 300px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
```

or

```
$(element).css({ width: '300px', 'padding-top': '10px', 'padding-bottom': '10px' });
```

Comment: Thanks, Jakob. I guess the part that puzzled me was there was no built-in way of setting it within the Button control. In other words, you'd set the button's width="100px" and height="25px" and it would automatically calculate the correct padding-top/bottom for the LABEL.

Comment: Was that a question? Setting height doesn't work because the label is not vertically centered on the button, but rather offset using padding. So to set a different height you have to use padding-top and padding-bottom.

Comment: No, more of a comment on the Button control. But now I understand how it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

normally:

```
$(theElement).css('height','...px').css('width','...px');
```

Comment: You can pass `.css()` an object as well: `.css({ height:10, width:10})`

Comment: And .height('Xpx') too (I think so)

Answer (score 5):

You can style the `.ui-button.ui-widget` (no spaces, must have both classes). (make sure your stylesheet appears below the jquery ui one). You can also style

```
.ui-button.ui-widget{
     height, width
}

.ui-button.ui-widget .ui-button-text{
    line-height, font-size
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution to make jquery UI button the same width.
First I need a method to get the max width.

```
var greatestWidth = 0;   // Stores the greatest width
function getMaxWidth() {
    var theWidth = $(this).width();   // Grab the current width

    if( theWidth > greatestWidth) {   // If theWidth > the greatestWidth so far,
        greatestWidth = theWidth;     //    set greatestWidth to theWidth
    }
}
```

Then I call this method after hooking up the button and set the size. example

```
  $('.selector')
        .button()
        .each(getMaxWidth);
  $('.selector').width(greatestWidth);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that putting `<small></small>` around the button tags helps a lot.  This is only beneficial in certain cases, but it helped me to reduce the size on a project I was working on.

Comment: Fixed...had to add back tips to make what I originally put show.

Answer (score 1):

You can the style the element with relative font-size.
If your button has the custome class 'buttonStyle' then add this to the CSS

```
.buttonStyle{
 font-size:0.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based off of this documentation http://api.jquery.com/height/ the below worked for:

```
$('#mybutton').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-plus" }, text: false}).height(20);
```